# Привязка к значению false

Tags: c#, wpf

Таким способом привязываю доступность одного чекбокса к состоянию IsChecked другого:`<CheckBox IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=myComboBox, Path=IsChecked}"></CheckBox>`
Но мне нужно сделать наоборот, чтобы первый чекбокс становился доступным, когда у второго состояние IsChecked = False. Каким образом это делается в WPF?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы можете использовать преобразователь значений (класс, реализующий IValueConverter.) Небольшой пример:

```
public class NegateConverter : IValueConverter
{

    public object Convert( object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture )
    {
        if ( value is bool ) {
            return !(bool)value;
        }
        return value;
    }

    public object ConvertBack( object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture )
    {
        if ( value is bool ) {
            return !(bool)value;
        }
        return value;
    }

}
```

Затем добавить его в свой XAML например так:

```
<UserControl xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyNamespace">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <local:NegateConverter x:Key="negate" />
    </UserControl.Resources>

    ...
    <CheckBox IsEnabled="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=myComboBox, Converter={StaticResource negate}}"
              Content="Show all" />

</UserControl>
```

Вопрос переведен [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3099402/wpf-element-databinding-for-isenabled-but-for-false).

Comment: Спасибо. Про конвертер читал, но думал, что он предназначен для более "сложных" привязок, нежели моя.

Answer (score 3):

Я бы предложил решить эту задачу с помощью триггеров.

```
<CheckBox Grid.Row="0" Name="myCheckBox"/>
<CheckBox Grid.Row="1">
    <CheckBox.Style>
        <Style TargetType="CheckBox">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=myCheckBox}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </CheckBox.Style>
</CheckBox>
```